# Piezoelectric Pressure Gauge

Tags: pressure

I would like to know how the pressure of a blast is measured when using a piezoelectric gauge as well as if this is the best way to measure the reflective wave from an explosion.

In better terms I guess would be maybe how does the sensor, sense, the passing pressure wave and what about it triggers it? Also I know there are other sensors out there that measures a different point of the wave and I would like to know how that differs from the pencil piezoelectric sensor.

Comment: Be more specific, your question is too broad in its current state.

Comment: In better terms I guess would be maybe how does the sensor, sense, the passing pressure wave and what about it triggers it? Also I know there are other sensors out there that measures a different point of the wave and I would like to know how that differs from the pencil piezoelectric sensor.

Comment: Not here, in comments, edit it into your question text instead.